# How to disable ligatures "inside the editor" while using vim for latex documents?

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex, conceal

I'm using vim for writing LaTeX documents. I also have [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net) installed. While I'm writing my documents *in the editor*, I get ligatures for that piece of text which is meaningful for the LaTeX language. For example, when I type an *en-dash* as defined by the language (`--`), I get a continuous dash line which is the size of two consecutive dashes, instead. I don't find this feature helpful and sometimes even confusing. So I want to see the document as it is while I'm using the editor. Is there any option to set this feature off?

Comment: There are now quite a few questions regarding the vim feature conceal in LaTeX files, e.g. https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/17686/1292, https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/18792/1292, https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5164/1292. IMHO I would consider them useful duplicates because not everyone is aware of the vim feature conceal and encounters it in different scenarios. However, the answer is always the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a part of standard filetype plugin, see `:h tex.vim` for a complete info.

That particular feature is controlled by `:h g:tex_conceal`

So it's enough to add `let g:tex_conceal = ''` to your vimrc (or to disable only ligatures and accents: `let g:tex_conceal = 'dmgs'`, i.e. no 'a' in tex_conceal's value).

Comment: So the technical term for this feature is _concealing_. That's maybe why I couldn't find anything relevant to my problem. I didn't know what it is called in vim. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also `let g:tex_conceal = 'bdmgs'` should have `b` because otherwise, it would also conceal bold and italics.

Comment: Also you can turn off conceal by setting `conceallevel`, but that’s the big hammer where Matt gives the little hammer

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, conceal in Vim is a general feature not confined to TeX. Notably, it's used by indentLines / vim-indent-guides and, perhaps, some other plugins. Fully disabling it is possible, but shouldn't be generally recommended.